# Excessive moderation? Closing questions as: "Ask vendor"

Tags: discussion

Here's what I'm talking about: https://serverfault.com/questions/676085/google-and-amazon-equivalent-of-azure-cloud-services 
One of the comments I got was that I should 'ask vendor'. Isn't this true for almost all the questions? The point of the question was to have a handy reference for me and others to comparable server side technologies.

Comment: The difference is that most questions are about resolving a problem. Contacting the vendor incurs costs in most cases, be it in support time, tickets spent or direct cost while the solution might be trivial. However you're asking for market research, which is not only not a real problem to be solved, it is very prone to change. If a problem has a resolution, that resolution is not going to change a year from now. There might be more ways to solve the problem by then, but still the original content is at its core valid. Asking what products Google offers may change over night.

Answer (score 10):

You are asking for a market overview, which I consider a product recommendation question. It has also other problems:

- It will be outdated quickly. This is one of the most important reasons why we don't like product recomendations.
- It's a subjective selection. Other vendors exist.
- It's the classic example of "We are not here to do your work for you". Comparing service offerings of providers is something you should be able to do yourself.